# Injecting meta tag on certain pages with directive

Tags: angularjs-directive

I have an application where I want to inject a smartBanner meta tag, but only on certain pages.

On my index page I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="ngBoilerplate" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
  <head>
    <title ng-bind="pageTitle"></title>   
<!-- add smart banner to select pages through smartBanner directive -->

<smart-banner></smart-banner>


 </head>
  <body>
    <ui-view></ui-view>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have a directive:

```
angular.module('boh.components.smartBanner', [])

.directive('smartBanner', function(){
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        template: '<meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=1080200000"></meta>',
        replace: true
    } ;
});
```

My question is, do I simply call the directive by injecting the directive into my other page controllers?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the best way to deal with this was to work through the PHP wrapper for the app.

I ended up with something like this:

```
<?php
    $urls = array("/app/explore", "/app/dashboard", "app/members",    "/app/account-settings", "/app/jobs");
      foreach ($urls as $key => $value) {
        if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $value ) { ?>
          <meta name="apple-itunes-app" content="app-id=########">
        <?php }
      }
    ?>
```